# Templated member functions cannot call non-templated member function from same class, C++

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I have written a class that handles all of the random number generation in my program. I am trying to implement functions within that class that take vectors or pointers to arrays and randomly chose one of their elements. I am using templates for these functions so they can choose from arrays or vectors containing any type.

However when compiling (MSVC 2012) I get errors with "error C3861: 'double0to1': identifier not found" for both template functions. double0To1 is a public member function of that class.

In rng.h:

```
#ifndef RNG_H
#define RNG_H

#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_real_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/random/variate_generator.hpp>
#include <vector>

class RNG
{
public:
    RNG(int seedIn);
    ~RNG(void);

    double double0To1();
    int positiveIntLessThan(int upperBound);

    template<class T> T* randomObjectInVector(std::vector<T*> vectorToChooseFrom);
    template<class T> T* randomObjectInArray(T** arrayToChooseFrom, int size);

private:
    int seed;
    boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<double> *distribution0To1;
    boost::mt19937 generator;
    boost::random::variate_generator<boost::mt19937, boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<double>> *mersenne0To1;
};

template<class T> T* RNG::randomObjectInVector(std::vector<T*> vectorToChooseFrom)
{
    double randNum=double0to1();
    double step=1/vectorToChooseFrom.size();

    int indexToTake=floor(randNum/step);

    return vectorToChooseFrom[indexToTake];
}

template<class T> T* RNG::randomObjectInArray(T** arrayToChooseFrom, int size)
{
    double randNum=double0to1();
    double step=1/size;

    int indexToTake=floor(randNum/step);

    return &((*arrayToChooseFrom)[indexToTake]);
}
```

And in rng.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "RNG.h"


RNG::RNG(int seedIn)
{
    seed=seedIn;
    generator.seed(seed);
    distribution0To1=new boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0, 1);
    mersenne0To1=new boost::random::variate_generator<boost::mt19937, boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<double> >(generator, *distribution0To1);
}

RNG::~RNG(void)
{
    delete distribution0To1;
}

double RNG::double0To1()
{
    return (*mersenne0To1)();
}

int RNG::positiveIntLessThan(int upperBound)
{
    double randomValue=double0To1();

    return int(upperBound*randomValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have a typo due to case sensitivity.

The function is called `double0To1`, yet you are calling `double0to1()`

Note the capital `T` in the function definition.  Identifiers in C++ are case sensitive.

Comment: Kicking myself now. I've been staring at this for a while, just needed a fresh pair of eyes I guess. Easy rep for you :)